# Is the Firestore arrayUnion method available via its REST API?

Tags: rest, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Firestore recently added a new function for working with arrays called arrayUnion. This allows for inserting a value into an array. My question: Is this feature available through the rest api? If so how?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not, looking at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/). You could always [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features).